# Mysql is slow in some cases while using 'LIKE'

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a fairly large table with 60million entries.

Lets call the table I have as `bigtable` and the column as `tracking_code`
(of type varchar(8)).

When I use the query

```
SELECT * FROM bigtable WHERE tracking_code LIKE 'SDMASGG_';
```

It takes 0.75 seconds to execute whereas the query

```
SELECT * FROM bigtable WHERE tracking_code LIKE 'SDMA_GGH';
```

takes more than 9 minuites.

I am intrigued by the selectivity shown by mysql towards the location of the '_'

Comment: maybe first query is cached?

Comment: In some case? Like is slow always. Best practice is avoid using LIKE. Bad new is that you can't optimize LIKE.

Comment: Do you have an index on the tracking_code column?  You are using the wildcard character "_" in both of your queries.
Mysql can make use of an index in a query using "like" if the wildcard characters are at the end of the string, such as in your first example.
In your second example, the wildcard is in the middle of your sting, so it can't use the index.

Comment: @Peter I don't think so, as I have tried with different tracking_codes and the response time was roughly the same.

Comment: mysql claims to use the index in both above cases, despite `_` being a wildcard;

Comment: Have you tried using `EXPLAIN` to see if there is any difference in execution?

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich I am perfectly happy with the 0.75 seconds response time of LIKE, just that pushing the '_' to somewhere in the middle does not agree well with LIKE !

Comment: I'm guessing the query engine can write `SDMASGG_` as "begins with..." but having an underscore in the middle is more complex.

Comment: @TrentonTrama I do have an index on the tracking_code column.

Comment: Though, as @pala_ says I don't see why the location of the '_' would render the index un-usable.

Comment: @user3392665 can you post the output of `explain` on both of the queries?

Comment: Try 'SDMA\\_GGH'  (Tnx to @DavidG for tip)

Comment: If you're going to escape the underscore, just use `=` instead of `like` since its not doing any pattern matching at all any more.

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich the underscore is important here as it's being used in a LIKE clause so escaping it would make it the same as `=`.

Comment: Yes. I was thinking first he is store some data that contains underscore. Anyway, if he have fixed range of allowed chars in string, for example A-Z, maybe first generate set of strings (SDMAAGGH, SDMA_BGGH, SDMACGGH....) and try to use IN() instead of LIKE. Not silver bullet, but for this specific case may work much faster with indexes.

Comment: The index is used with `LIKE` unless the wildcard is the first character

Comment: @Eilidh and pala_ EXPLAIN produces identical output for both the queries

Comment: How many rows returned from each variation?

Comment: @RickJames 1000 in the first case and 160000 in the second

Answer (score 1):

My comment was partially correct, though I made the mistake of thinking that an index wasn't used if the wildcard was anywhere other than the end of a string in a LIKE comparison.

Mysql BTREE indexes can be used in LIKE comparisons as long as

[the argument to LIKE is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-btree-hash.html)

If you have a wildcard in the middle of the string, it will only use the characters from the beginning to the first wildcard.
In your second example, this means your query only uses the index to match "SDMA".  After that, it will scan the remaining rows to find the match.

[Only the part before the first wildcard serves as an access predicate.
The remaining characters do not narrow the scanned index range—non-matching entries are just left out of the result.](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning)

Comment: Almost right, it won't scan the rows when it reaches the wildcard but it will iterate through the larger number of matching index entries

Answer (score 0):

There is the option to use a Full Text Search instead of LIKE. The only foreseeable issue I can see with this, is if you're not using myISAM.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

In the case you're using something else like INNODB, you're going to have to use something like [Lucene](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/techniques/indexing-databases.html).

Comment: InnoDB `FULLTEXT` is available in 5.6.  (It's not identical to MyISAM.)

Answer (score 0):

> 1000 in the first case and 160000 in the second

It takes a lot longer to shovel 160K rows to the client than to shovel just 1K.

A "fairer" test would be to do `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` instead of `SELECT * ...`.

Comment: The SELECT COUNT(*)... for the first case it took 0.0 sec and 24 sec for the second.

Comment: I also tried SELECT COUNT(*)... with other tracking_codes:  SELECT count(*) FROM bigtable WHERE tracking_code LIKE 'SDMASGG_'; count is 1000 returned in 0.0 sec.  Whereas SELECT count(*) FROM bigtable WHERE tracking_code LIKE 'SD_ASGGH'; count is 653 still it takes 20 sec.

Comment: "0.0 sec" sounds like the Query cache kicked in.  `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` will avoid it.